# pycharm use anaconda interpreter

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda, interpreter

I use anaconda's interpreter as pycharm interpreter. I wonder if all the module included in the "conda list" should appears in pycharm. In my situation, the anwser is NO, I need to install the modules which are already included in the "conda list"
Is it normal?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Settings -> Project Interpreter` you can switch to the `Conda Package Manager` mode.

[image]

Also in the `Project Interpreter` drop-down menu above, make sure you are using the correct `Conda Environment`.